Doze Mode no maintenance
I would love to see the Doze I want to disable the maintenance window in Doze mode. How do I do this via ADB?
I googled but didnt find anything related to my question.. I just know how to force doze via ADB and change settings.. But i dont know how to exactly just disable the maintenance windows
